# CDN SSL Sertificate - Two web sites on IIS 7.0 - Port 443 Issue

Tags: https, cdn, iis7, windows-server-2008

I am using [imperva CDN](https://www.imperva.com/) as proxy for my two web sites.
Also i am using IIS 7.0 (Windows server 2008-R2) as my web host.
Web site 1 is like : `www.test-1.com`
Web site 2 is like : `www.test-2.com`
After config CDN and DNS records every thing is working very well.
Now i want to use ssl certificate of CDN for both web sites.
For doing this i did https (`port 443`) binding for web site 1 with **default certificate of windows**.

[image: port 443]

And did https (`port 444`) binding for web site 2 with **default certificate of windows**.
Problem is i can not use same port 443 for web site 2 & i forced to redirect port 443 to 444 in CDN config.

How do i use same port 443 for both web sites in IIS 7.0?
Also tell me is using **default certificate of windows** the correct way for ssl certificate on origin side?

---

**EDIT :**
I only have `one ip address` and i am using it for both web sites in IIS.

Comment: Please [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214475/multiple-domains-in-443-port-in-same-ip) - Solution on this questions is for IIS 8.0 & there is no selected answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS 7.0 isn't able to handle it. Including the host name in the SSL handshake is a relatively new innovation. It wasn't so long ago that you had to have a dedicated IP address for each host name for HTTPS to work. I'm not sure when IIS started supporting HTTPS virtual hosting, but IIS 7.0 didn't support that.

IIS 7.0 was released 14 years ago and support for it ended in January 2020. You should not be using it anymore.

Comment: @SilverLight I made my statements in this answer more definite than in my comments based on your confirmation.  If you've found a reference it would be nice if we could include it.